# Verification Activity Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation that schedule everyday with different steps.

> SQL --> verification (if record aren't > 0 will stop) --> Filter-->send
> email.

If first run there is the error `(record are < 0)`, so stops the automation the next day, does the automation restart if I don't correct the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by error you mean is, due to SQL, in the first activity, the automation will stop for that instance, but will not get paused. It will run again on the next schedule.

If by error you mean, that the SQL returned 0 records and the verification activity stops the automation, the automation will stop for that instance. It will run again on the next schedule.

Read more : [SQL Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) [Verification Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=mc_as_verification_activity.htm&type=5)

Comment: thank you for your timely and very helpful reply. I mean the verification stopped me as the returned records did not match what I wanted.

Comment: The automation will not pause. It will stop for that run, It will again run the next time it is scheduled for.